# Use SCSS style files within AngularDart 5 and Dart 2

Tags: sass, dart, angular-dart

I’m working with ***Dart 2*** and ***AngularDart 5***.

⚠ I searched online about my question, but I didn’t find a satisfactory answer.

❔ Can somebody explain *all* the steps I need to include and to work with **SCSS** style files within my AngularDart application?

I started with quickstart application that you can find [here](https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/angular/guide/setup).

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Add a dev dependency to your pubspec.yaml for `sass_builder:
   ^2.0.0`.
2. Run `pub get` to download the new dependencies.
3. Create a sass file ex: `lib/app_component.scss` and add some styles to it.
4. Add a the ***compiled*** css stylesheet to your the @Component annotation in `lib/app_component.dart`:
   `styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],`

The css file will be generated by sass_builder during the build process.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using angluar_components. One could simply turn it on:

1. Create a build.yaml file with the following content :

   ```
   targets:
     $default:
       builders:
         angular_components|scss_builder:
           enabled: True
   ```
2. Use the following convention for the `styleUrl` annotations:
   `styleUrls: const ['app_component.scss.css']`
3. Write your sass in the `*.scss` files.

Comment: Technically sass_builder isn't included in the build tool. It is a dependency of angular_components.

This technique does work, but you are relying on the sass_builder package as a transitive dependency through the angular_components package. If you stop using angular_components or never were to begin with then this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

With newest versions:

1. Surprise: In `styleUrls` are in a different CSS filename (not with the `.scss.css` extension, just `.css`; e.g. `app_component.css`, but the styles are in `app_component.scss`).
2. Surprise: In `app_component.scss`, import without `lib` in the path:

```
@import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/mixins';
```

3. I am using this command:

```sh
pub run build_runner serve --verbose
```

See with package info:
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/374#issuecomment-636344237