# How to install Dart Sass?

Tags: sass

The instructions on the website say:

**You can install Sass on Windows, Mac, or Linux by downloading the package for your operating system from GitHub and adding it to your PATH. That's all—there are no external dependencies and nothing else you need to install.**

I downloaded the Windows package from here: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.10.1 and now what? Where do I place the zip? Do I need to extract it? I have no idea what this means - "To install Dart Sass 1.10.1, download one of the packages above and add it to your PATH." Sass is not being recognized when I try to check the version from the command line.

Can someone provide a step by step guide?

I've also installed Ruby, if it matters (but I don't want Ruby Sass, I want Dart Sass).

Comment: Don't know if you still need help, but look at this question: [Use SCSS style files within AngularDart 5 and Dart 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631951/10277106)

Comment: Firstly, uninstall Ruby Sass, then look at my answer below.

Answer (score 28):

For windows 10

1. Go here [dart-sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/) and download dart-sass which is suitable for your operating system.
2. Extract it where you want.
3. Open windows search and search this "system environment variables" then click it to open.
   [image]
4. Click "Environment Variables"
   [image]
5. Under system varibles find the PATH variable, select it, and click "Edit". 
   [image]
6. If there is no PATH variable, click "New" and write here PATH.
   [image]
   [image]
7. Go your dard-sass folder and copy directory.
   [image]
8. Add your directory to the beginning of the variable value followed by ; (a semicolon). For example, if the value was C:\Windows\dart-sass, change it to C:\Users\Me\bin;C:\Windows\dart-sass. If there is not another directory just add your directory here. Then click "Ok".
   [image]
9. Open "Command Prompt".
   [image]
10. Write here "sass --version" and click enter to be sure it installed correctly.
    [image]
11. Create style.scss and style.css file.
    [image]
12. Write on Command Prompt "cd" then your directory(where is style.scss and style.css file). For example "cd Desktop\webdev" 
    [image]
13. Then write this "sass --watch style.scss style.css". Then minimize it.
    [image]
14. That's it. You can open your text editor then style.scss file and write your Sass code. It's automatically compile to the css code.

https://katiek2.github.io/path-doc/

Comment: Here is a link that shows Windows and Linux: https://jakeprice.tech/2018/07/29/setting-up-dart-sass-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu

$ sudo snap install dart-sass

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed to install dart sass on linux (specifically, a WSL ubuntu instance on my Windows 10 machine).

1. Download the package from github. At present, that's at https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.72.0

   - I chose *dart-sass-1.72.0-linux-x64.tar.gz*
   - It downloads into the windows downloads folder, as
     usual
   - The downloaded file can be accessed from a wsl ubuntu
     shell, such as with `$ ls /mnt/c/users/matt/downloads`
2. Extract the downloaded file and save it into the `/opt/` directory with:

   ```
   $ sudo tar -xvzf /mnt/c/users/matt/downloads/dart-sass-1.72.0-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/
   ```

   - result: there is now a subdirectory called *dart-sass*
3. Add the new directory to `PATH` permanently by adding to the *.bashrc* file:

   - open the *.bashrc* file in a text editor. The file is
     found under my
     home directory, i.e. `$ ls ~ -a` -> shows *.bashrc*
   - write the following to the end of the file and save:

     ```
     # Add sass to path
     export PATH="/opt/dart-sass:$PATH"
     ```
4. Open a new terminal and confirm sass is installed:

   ```
   $ sass --version                                                                                  
   1.72.0
   ```