# When I install SASS with NPM, where is the executable on my computer?

Tags: eclipse, sass

I am developing in Windows 10. I do some of my web development in Eclipse and like to use SASS in developing my CSS. Eclipse needs to access SASS in order to compile the SCSS into CSS.

I went to the SASS website and they give a variety of options for installing SASS. I chose to install it with npm and did so successfully on my C: drive. Now I need to know the name of the SASS executable and where it is on my C: drive so I can point to it in my Eclipse tool builders.

I've tried searching for files containing "sass" in the file name but the Windows search utility is useless: it's been running for hours and most of the file names it finds don't even contain "sass". It finds nothing at all when I search on "sass.exe".

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on my own.

First, I should explain that I was initially using Ruby Sass but that wouldn't work when I tried to use it yesterday for the first time in a few months. I vaguely remember something about Ruby Sass being scheduled for deprecation so maybe that's why it stopped working suddenly? Anyway, I needed it to work again but found the information at the SASS website so vague as to raise more questions than it answered so I posted here.

Insomnia has me up in the middle of the night so I started digging and decided to try the SASS website again. This time, I opted for the "Install Anywhere (standalone)" instructions and grabbed Dart SASS. It wasn't intuitively obvious how to install that either but I searched here at StackOverflow and found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571814/how-to-install-dart-sass), which I followed carefully.

I found that for my particular situation, I didn't need to create the two files, `style.css` and `style.scss`, and I didn't have to execute the `watch` command either. However, the syntax of the SASS command for the Eclipse Builder had changed a bit: `--sourcemaps=none` changed to `--no-source-maps` and I didn't need the `--style` parameter at all since the default value for `style` is exactly what I wanted, namely `expanded`. By the way, the executable isn't an `.exe` file, it's `sass.bat`.

Now my SCSS compiles to CSS cleanly and I'm back in business.