# Trying a scss file to css by using terminal, sass doesn't work

Tags: html, css, sass

i'm learning html and i'm in the very beginning. i've written this variables.scss file and trying to turn css file. this is what i wrote to VS Code terminal: **sass variables.scss:variables.css**

and this is my error msg:

```
sass : The term 'sass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify  
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sass variables.scss:variables.css
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sass:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

i said okey, i just need to install sass i guess and write to the terminal:
**npm install -g node-sass**

```
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that    
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install -g node-sass
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

sooo i have no idea what should i do or not (i tried other stuff also end up error msgs)

trying to variables.scss to turn css file.

Comment: sass team recommeded  install dart-sass for command line. it is fast. check [sass install on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571814/how-to-install-dart-sass)

Comment: i tried that in command prompt and says " 'sass' is not recognized as an internal or extarnal command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: R u using window os ?

Comment: if you use vs code [live-sass](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass)

Answer (score 2):

1. First, you need to download and install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).
2. Second, (as the screenshot looks like you are on Windows) ensure the path to the executable has been added to your [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864253/11788062).
3. You may need to restart your computer after this for the changes to take effect.
4. Run `npm install -g sass` in the terminal.
5. Run `sass variables.scss variables.css` in the terminal.