# Is there anything like GruntJs for Dart?

Tags: javascript, dart, gruntjs, angular-dart

I have been using GruntJs to precompile and post process my SCSS/CSS for my JavaScript projects. After working with AngularDart a bit I have been wondering whether there is something like GruntJs for Dart.

The grunt tasks I am currently using are:

- grunt-contrib-watch
- gunt-sass
- grunt-postcss

**Is there a task runner for Dart that would provide me the same outcome as GruntJs?**

Comment: Perhaps https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/grinder but not widely used. Your question is off topic on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

Build runner should auto re-compile Sass using the scss_builder. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sass_builder

There isn't really a concept of postcss in the ecosystem at the moment that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

The dart sass compiler is built into the build tool. Using it is rather [straight forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609938/use-scss-style-files-within-angulardart-5-and-dart-2/52820816#52820816).

I also haven't seen anything like postcss in Dart, it doesn't seem to be a need.